# Error: not all code paths return a value for an awaitable function

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a piece of code:

```
...
await func();
```

where function "func" is defined as:

```
private Task func()
{
}
```

and this function definition gives an error:

> func(): not all code paths return a value.

What kind of value it requires from me here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing the [`async`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) keyword in your function:

```
private async Task func()
{
}
```

Without it you are defining a function that is returning an object of type `Task` but you have no row of `return someTask;` and therefore get that compilation error. So unless you add it you will have to return some task.

Otherwise, when specifying the `async` keyword you state that this function will be executing some code that can be awaited. If in it you do not `await` any `Task` you will receive a warning of: `"This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously."`. For more about the warning message read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303133/warning-message-in-async-method-saying-that-it-lacks-await-operators).

This will explain better [How and When to use `async` and `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Comment: When I define it like this, I get a warning: "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously."

Comment: @Kibernetik - Did this help you understand the issue?

Comment: Thank you very much for your links Gilad Green! I will mark your answer as a solution and will study them. Seems I am lacking some basic understanding of await/async functionality...

Answer (score 2):

You have a return type for the method but you don't return anything.

```
private Task func()
{
  return new Task();//the task
}
```

Comment: But my other functions which also have Task return type (but they are async) also do not return anything and do not give this kind of error.

Comment: Gilad Green nailed this one