# Issues converting Task based C# sample to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have following C# method that uses System.Threading.Tasks.Task class.

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    HttpResponseMessage response =
                             new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    response.Content = new StringContent(Content);
    response.RequestMessage = Request;
    return Task.FromResult(response);
  }
```

I am having some issues writing above code in VB.Net. I have tried the following, but VS 2107 shows an error for the last line in the below function  saying `FromResult is not a member of Task`.

**Question**: What would be correct equivalent of C# code in VB.Net for the last line in C# method?

```
Public Async Function ExecuteAsync(ByVal cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    response.Content = New StringContent(Content)
    response.RequestMessage = Request
    Return   Task.FromResult(Of HttpResponseMessage) (response) 'this line shows error
End Function
```

**Screenshot of error**

[image: VB.Net error in Vs 2017 code editor]

The full C# class that contains this original method is as below.

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public GlobalExceptionHandler()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //

    }
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new TextPlainErrorResult
               {
                   Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
                   Content = "Oops! Sorry! Something went wrong." +
                             "Our team has been informed and we will try to fix it as soon as possible."
               };
        base.Handle(context);
    }

    private class TextPlainErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response =
                             new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            response.Content = new StringContent(Content);
            response.RequestMessage = Request;
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```

The converted VB.Net code of above C# code is as below.

```
Public Class GlobalExceptionHandler
    Inherits ExceptionHandler

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Handle(ByVal context As ExceptionHandlerContext)
        context.Result = New TextPlainErrorResult With {
            .Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
            .Content = "Oops! Sorry! Something went wrong." & "Our team has been informed and we will try to fix it as soon as possible."
        }
        MyBase.Handle(context)
    End Sub

    Private Class TextPlainErrorResult
        Implements IHttpActionResult

        Public Property Request As HttpRequestMessage
        Public Property Content As String

        Public Function ExecuteAsync(ByVal cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)

            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            response.Content = New StringContent(Content)
            response.RequestMessage = Request

            Return new Task.FromResult(response)

        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186583/discussion-on-question-by-sunil-issues-converting-task-based-c-sample-to-vb-net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost correctly translated

```cs
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response =
                             new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    response.Content = new StringContent(Content);
    response.RequestMessage = Request;
    return Task.FromResult(response);
}
```

as

```vb
Public Async Function ExecuteAsync(ByVal cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    response.Content = New StringContent(Content)
    response.RequestMessage = Request
    Return Task.FromResult(Of HttpResponseMessage) (response) 'this line shows error
End Function
```

The only mistake was the addition of `Async` that was not present in the original, so it should be removed:

```vb
Public Function ExecuteAsync(ByVal cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    response.Content = New StringContent(Content)
    response.RequestMessage = Request
    Return Task.FromResult(Of HttpResponseMessage) (response) 'this line shows error
End Function
```

`Async` is not a part of a method signature and is not a requirement for writing methods that can be consumed with `await` - as long as the method returns a `Task`, it can be awaited.

The C# original does not use `async` in its definition because it is in fact synchronous (and so is your VB translation). Using `Async` on that function will only result in a [compiler warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21303209/11683), fixing which will require removing the `Async`.

The use of `Task.FromResult(Of HttpResponseMessage) (response)` [is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19696462/11683) and may even be simplified to `Task.FromResult(response)` because the compiler is able to infer the type.

If for you it shows an error about `FromResult` not being a member of `Task` (which it [certainly is](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,11a386e7d7cae64a)), there there must be another class named `Task` defined in your solution that shadows the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` class. In that case refer to it in a more elaborate way, e.g. `Tasks.Task.FromResult(response)` or `Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(response)`.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent and detailed explanation. It's very clear now.  I need to find some good book in VB.Net that explains stuff like you have.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Task.FromResult` in the last line:

```
   Public Async Function ExecuteAsync(ByVal cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
        Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        response.Content = New StringContent("")
        response.RequestMessage = Request
        Return   response 
    End Function
```

Comment: I tried this, but now it gives another error saying: `Value of type HttpResponseMessage cannot be converted to Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)`

Comment: @Sunil this is compile-time error you get? Or run-time error? How could you get that? I tried that code and I neither get compile time nor run-time error.